# RSS and RSS page for each post

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, rss

This is my RSS feed format:

```
<item>
<title></title>
<link></link>
<description></description>
<pubDate></pubDate>
<guid></guid>
<dc:date></dc:date>
</item>
```

I want to dipsplay the last 7 posts with CSS style, so I use this code:

```
<?php
$url = "**THE URL I AM SCRAPING DATA FROM**";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
$i = 0;
if (!empty($rss))
{
    $site = $rss
        ->channel->title;
    $sitelink = $rss
        ->channel->link;
    foreach ($rss
        ->channel->item as $item)
    {
        $title = $item->title;
        $link = $item->link;
        $description = $item->description;
        $item->description = strip_tags($item->description);
        $date = $item->pubDate;
        $pubDate = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($date));
        if ($i >= 7) break;
?>

<div class="post-item">
    <div class="post-item-wrap">
        <div class="post-image">
            <a href="<?php echo $link;?>">
                <img alt="" src="images/news/nra.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="post-item-description">
            <span class="post-meta-date"><?php echo $pubDate;?></span>
            <h2><a href="<?php echo $link ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $title;?>
            </a></h2>
            <p><?php echo implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $description), 0, 30)) . "..";?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo $link;?>" class="item-link">learn more <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

***Now I want each of these 7 posts to have unique id.
I need script to generate item -> title and item -> description depending on the item -> link.
(If I click first xml post for example it will take me to page where I can display the title and description according to which post I clicked)***

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use this code get last 7 items

```
array_slice($rss->channel->item, -7);
```

Comment: But how to display each items individually.
I have main page - rss.php
I want to do rss.php?feed1, rss.php?feed2, rss.php?feed3 from the items

Answer (score 0):

If url is "rss.php?feed=1" or "rss.php?feed=2"

```
$rssSno=$_GET['feed'];

$output = array_slice($rss->channel->item, ($rssSno-1),1);
```